# Angular form ng-required expression called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I am building a form in which my fields can have mandatory conditions based on other fields. I'm using something like

```
ng-required="ctrl.evaluateCond(item.condition)"
```

for each of my fields and this works. whenever the user changes some input the entire for with all it's fields are reevaluated. The problem is that it seems to call this evaluateCond function several times for each field ?
That is a problem because I later on will have conditions that make calls to a server to get some data needed for the validation and this call of course should only be made once for performance reasons. I was thinking if I should make some sort of singleton and have a boolean variable initialized when it starts so that when it is progress, other calls to it will be blocked until that boolean has been reversed back. Sort of a primitive locking mechanism. 
This however seems like kind of an ugly workaround and I wanted to know if anyone had other ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called multiple times because angular supports two way data binding. When a scope variable changes, the `$digest` function triggers the respective listeners, recomputes the values and view is re-rendered.

In your case you can use `debounce` model option on your input field so that model will update only after specified time interval, this way you can limit the frequency of function calls associated with `ng-required`.

**Example**

```
<input type="text" name="userName"
             ng-model="user.name"
             ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
```